# Can a JFrame show a Process?

Tags: java, swing, process

Question, can you create a process(in this case opening google chrome) and display the result(in this case the browser) inside a JFrame? I don't want a separate window to pop up.

Comment: Not without a lot of cooperation from the other program.

Comment: if the program has a Java API it could be possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it can. JxBrowser library is what you need. It gives you a possibility to embed a rich web browser component into your Swing-based Java desktop applications. So web documents, inside your application will look exactly like in a web browser that they are designed. 
Below is the link of few examples involving jxBrowser and download page:
https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/Quick-Start.html

Comment: From what I've looked at your answer seems to have answered my question! Thank you!